# Does Kendo UI support chrome apps/extentions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, kendo-ui, google-chrome-app, kendo-mobile

I tried to port my succesefuly worked my kendo-based site as chrome app. But app does not works. I found on chrome developer console exception message *"extensions::platformApp:17 history.pushState is not available in packaged apps."* on
*`<script src="kendo/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>`* string

I found the same problem on angular with a solution, but did not found for the Kendo.

Any way to resolve it?

Comment: `window.history` is disabled for chrome app, see [Disabled Web Features](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated), Navigation part.

More infomation can be found here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-reviews/iMXu8RvnG-U

Comment: yes I found already that window.history is disable. There is any possibility to use KendoUI for the chrome apps?

Comment: May be some patches or adopded version KendoUI?

Answer (score 1):

By default Kendo UI (and Mobile) doesn't use the History API, due to its rather limited support in the past. If you explicitly enabled it, you can delete this option, though you will probably have to update your navigation throughout the apps:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/application#configuration-pushState

Comment: Unfornutaly I see exception without any js code, only kendo files included.

Comment: You need to run Kendo UI (or any other library that uses eval) in a sandboxed iframe, so that it can work. When you need the Chrome extensions API, you can communicate with the external app with postMessage. Alternatively check this jQuery plugin, which may help:

https://github.com/burkeholland/pkg